open Webui : how to create a new chat, sending a question and getting the answer with python
I use open webui to manage different LLM Model. I would like to use it as my central point for llm management. For example if I code a python function to connect to a model, I juste have to change de LLM model name to test another LLM.
But, even considering elements here : https://myopenwebuiurl/api/v1/docs I'm not progressing in my work.
Curently I defined 2 functions:
def create_new_chat(api_url, api_key):
    """Crée un nouveau chat et retourne l'ID du chat."""
    headers = {
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {api_key}',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    payload = {'chat': {}}  
    response = requests.post(f'{api_url}/chats/new', json=payload, headers=headers)
    return response.json()# Création d'un chat
new_chat_response = create_new_chat(API_URL, API_KEY)

and
def send_message_to_chat(api_url, api_key, chat_id, message):
    """Envoie un message au chat spécifié et retourne la réponse du serveur."""
    headers = {
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {api_key}',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    payload = {
        'chat': {
            'content': message,
            'role': 'user',  
        }
    }
    response = requests.post(f'{api_url}/chats/{chat_id}', json=payload, headers=headers)
    return response.json()

it seems something is happening because I don't have error message, and whem I'm going in the interface, the new chat is existing in the list of chats, but if I select it it is completly white and empty, like if something was not loaded.
Any recommandation on how to create a chat, post an answer and get the result with python?

a begining of answer here : https://github.com/open-webui/open-webui/discussions/1349
